# Python Probability Aligorithm

Tags: probability

I am looking for help with a Python algorithm that will take a percent or fraction (such as 45% or 4500/10000) and testing it multiple times, and seeing how many times it comes out true, and how many times it comes out false.

Basically, I am looking for an algorithm that will take a probability, test it multiple times, and give us results on how many times you, say, survived, or died.

Is this possible, and can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the following for the number of trials you want:

- Generate a random integer between 0 and the denominator (if it's a fraction) or real number between 0 and 1 (if it's a percent)
- If the value is less than the numerator/percent, record a failure, otherwise record a success

You can find information on generating random values in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html), and how you determine whether you're working with a percent or a fraction will depend on how you accept and parse user input.